# autocomplete mysql huge table

Tags: mysql, autocomplete, sphinx

I have table with 5 million records.
response from mysql is so long between 1-5 sec. How can this optimize to  get 0.5 sec for request

```
CREATE TABLE `search` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

request

```
SELECT  text 
FROM search 
WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('+some +string*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
LIMIT 10
```

**update**

maybe in this case sphinx is best solution?

Comment: You need a bigger boat.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great summary of methods for doing a search like this.

http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql

A FULLTEXT index will get you a much faster result than you're currently getting.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on your text column.

Comment: i have FULLTEXT index, or need add one